# Javascript Class - Cannot set a property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code to create a class in javascript.... Now i will only pass the ID of the 'website' and then via an ajax call i will get the rest of the information from the database (JSON ENCODED).

Now my only problem is that when i see whats in the object at the end its only showing the id.

The ajax calls works fine because if i alert this.address after success (ajax) its displaying the result.

What I presume is that I cannot set a property with an ajax request... Can you help?

```
function website(id) {
     this.id = id; //id


     $.ajax({  //website_information
      type: "GET",
      url: '/proc.php?proc=website_name&id=' + this.id + '',
      success: function(data){
      var tmp = $.parseJSON(data);
     this.address = tmp.website_address;

     this.name = tmp.website_name;
      }
    });

    }

    var obj = new website('20');
    obj.alertwebsite();
    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Two problems: (1) at the moment you call `console.log(obj)`, the Ajax request did not finished yet (though [since browser consoles are weird](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/), you might not even notice that). (2) `this` inside the success callback refers to the `jqXHR` object, not the instance you created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first is that `$.ajax` is asynchronous. That means it returns *before* the request is complete. The `success` function is run when the request is complete, but `obj.alertwebsite()` will be run before.

The second problem is the value of `this` within an AJAX callback. Within the callback, `this` is set to an object containing all the settings for the AJAX call.  This means you are setting `address` and `name` properties on this object. There are two ways around this. The first is `that = this` as in other answers. The nicer way is to use the `context` setting in the AJAX call:

```
function website(id) {
    this.id = id; //id

    $.ajax({ //website_information
        type: "GET",
        url: '/proc.php?proc=website_name&id=' + this.id + '',
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            var tmp = $.parseJSON(data);
            this.address = tmp.website_address;

            this.name = tmp.website_name;
        }
    });
}
```

This allows you to customise what `this` means inside the callback.  This is documented in [the jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 2):

the `this` inside the AJAX callback may not be referring to the "object-to-be" that your constructor is making. Instead, we preserve the `this` from the outside by putting it in another variable, like say `that`. Then we use `that` to refer to our object-to-be in the AJAX callback.

```
function website(id) {
    var that = this; //preserve "this"
    this.id = id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/proc.php?proc=website_name&id=' + this.id + '',
        success: function(data){
            var tmp = $.parseJSON(data);
            that.address = tmp.website_address;  //using "that"
            that.name = tmp.website_name;        //using "that"
       }
    });
}
```

also, you are calling blindly in your `obj.alertwebsite()` because you don't know if your website info (`that.address` and `that.name`) has been loaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
function website(id) {
    // you need to save "this"
    var self = this;
     this.id = id; //id


     $.ajax({  //website_information
      type: "GET",
      url: '/proc.php?proc=website_name&id=' + this.id + '',
      //async: false, // optionally, if you want to get it back syncronously, so the console.log after the function call will already have the data
      success: function(data){
      var tmp = $.parseJSON(data);
     // you need to use the saved "this"
     self.address = tmp.website_address;

     self.name = tmp.website_name;
      }
    });
}
```